# Trouble with a heightmap adjusting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, javascript

I have a 2D grid of integers. The user can pick any location and increase or decrease its number by one. The algorithm should adjust all eight adjacent locations so there is no more than a difference of one between them.

I've go things working mostly but there must be an edge case I'm missing as after making a few adjustments one of the locations can go wonky (much more of a difference than one).

Here is a screenshot of the grid once it goes wonky.
[image: Wonky Grid]

The javascript to so this is

```
var moveDown = function (x, y) {
    var updated = false;
    if (x-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x-1][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x-1][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && y-1 >= 0 && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y-1]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y-1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }
    if (x+1 < size && y+1 < size && Math.abs(grid[x][y] - grid[x+1][y+1]) > 1) {
        grid[x+1][y+1] -= 1;
        updated = true;
    }

    if (updated) {
        if (x-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x-1, y); }
        if (x+1 < size) { moveDown(x+1, y); }
        if (y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x, y-1); }
        if (y+1 < size) { moveDown(x, y+1); }
        if (x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x-1, y-1); }
        if (x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < size) { moveDown(x-1, y+1); }
        if (x+1 < size && y-1 >= 0) { moveDown(x+1, y-1); }
        if (x+1 < size && y+1 < size) { moveDown(x+1, y+1); }
    }
}
```

I've got a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jzaun/wt7m3hs5/) that I've been using to play with things.

How can I fix things to make it work properly?

Comment: Can't be bothered to debug JS really, but, whatever the problem, reliably reproducing it is half the work. I can't see that in your question, so I assume you've not done that. Here's a way to reproduce it in 8 steps: pick a square near the middle, and the square to the right of it. Then increment, alternating between one and the other. On the 8-th increment I get this weird effect. Next step would be to examine the state of the board after the 7-th increment and step through the update in the 8th.

Comment: Your code appears to be recursive (calling itself). Did you trace out how many times it is calling itself? Can you prove that the recursive call is not infinite? (Proving that a piece of recursive function does not result in an infinite loop is a skill expected of anyone who writes code for software.)

Comment: @rwong That's quite a lengthy way of saying "You've got a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` in your console!"

Comment: @Ordous I'm trying to throw an exception (also known as reprimand) as humanly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments, your code is recursive, and in some situations it hits an infinite recursion.

When that infinite recursion is triggered, the outcome depends on the Javascript engine being used. In some versions, an error message "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" will appear in the error console. (This is the case for Chrome.) Other Javascript engines may handle it differently, and maybe in not-so-nice ways.

The unusual numerical values are displayed only if the Javascript engine interrupts the execution and still refreshes the page rendering (without executing the code further).

You can implement your original idea using for-loops, without using recursion.

You can get some ideas from [Morphological Image Processing](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic4.htm).